# Punteggiatura: quale forma è corretta?

Tags: punctuation

1. La vera domanda è: possiamo fidarci?
2. La vera domanda è, possiamo fidarci?
3. La vera domanda è (:) "possiamo fidarci?"
4. La vera domanda è possiamo fidarci?

Le prime due mi sembrano sbagliate, perché mi è sempre stato insegnato che il verbo e il complemento oggetto, e così la copula e il predicato nominale, non vanno separati da segni di interpunzione.

Escluderei anche la quarta, perché potrebbe risultare ambigua scritta così e, oltretutto, nella lingua parlata ci sarebbe una breve pausa tra 'è' e la domanda, e questa pausa non verrebbe riportata se mancasse del tutto la punteggiatura.

La terza, poi, mi sembra corretta ma non mi convince: la punteggiatura mi sembra, al contrario della quarta, troppa, e le virgolette mi dànno l'idea di discorso diretto.

Qual è allora la forma giusta?

Comment: A naso (e quindi non la metto come risposta): nella versione 1 non vedo nulla di male. Dopotutto anche in una frase come «Daniele disse: “Ciao a tutti”» c'è un po' di punteggiatura tra verbo e complemento oggetto.

Comment: Secondo me la corretta è la 1: i 2 punti vengono usati per spiegare e in questo caso separano un'oggettiva (una frase che fa da complemento oggetto e non un vero complemento oggetto). Nella 2, la virgola è solo un "respiro", quindi non è adatta. Nella 3, scusa, ma non ho mai visto i due punti tra parentesi. Nella 4, come dici tu, manca la pausa che c'è quando si dice a voce.

Comment: @AndreaTosoni: suppongo che le parentesi nella 3 servano solo per proporre due varianti, con e senza i due punti.

Comment: Non l'avevo capita così ... perché senza parentesi per me ricadeva nella 1. Pensavo fosse un modo un po' inusuale di scrivere la punteggiatura.

Comment: Direi la prima o, con l'interrogativa indiretta, *La vera domanda è se possiamo fidarci.* Eviterei le virgolette, che sanno di discorso riportato, mentre qui è una domanda che pone chi parla.

Comment: Penso che la vera risposta sia : La vera domanda è : "possiamo fidarci?"

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @minidiable. Qui ci aspettiamo una risposta più approfondita e argomentata.

Comment: @charo, infatti, io ho messo la risposta argomentata e ho preso due punti negativi.

Comment: Esempi di Google Books che confermano quanto detto da @egreg, AndreaTosoni e DaG: https://books.google.com/books?id=sesQyned7h4C&pg=PT188&dq=%22la+domanda+importante+%C3%A8:+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBjgKahUKEwjrw-asmcnIAhXGsxQKHR10D2Y, https://books.google.com/books?id=ZTorlP9JtqAC&pg=PA14&dq=%22la+domanda+importante+%C3%A8:+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgUahUKEwictpj-mcnIAhXE0RQKHb4oDss

Comment: Ho cercato esempi in libri che penso siano seri e ben scritti (e anche interessanti).

Answer (score 3):

In ordine di erroneità:

1. > La vera domanda è possiamo fidarci?

   Non è corretta perché non c'è nessuna pausa, cosa che, come correttamente     obbietti, ci sarebbe nel parlato.
2. > La vera domanda è (:) "possiamo fidarci?"

   I due punti con virgolette introducono tipicamente quanto riportato da  fonti esterne alla comunicazione, in modo diretto. Ad esempio:

   > Alice disse a Bob: "Come stai?"

   con un discorso indiretto avremmo:

   > Alice chiese a Bob come stesse.
3. > La vera domanda è, possiamo fidarci?

   La virgola introduce una piccola pausa nel discorso ma mi sembra grammaticalmente scorretto l'introduzione di una proposizione oggettiva, proprio per la separazione tra verbo e complemento oggetto.

Quindi,

> La vera domanda è: possiamo fidarci?

è il metodo corretto; i due punti, infatti, hanno funzione principalmente clarificatoria di quanto appena detto ed enumerativa (lista di elementi).

Altro segno di interpunzione valido sarebbero i puntini sospensivi in caso volessi delineare una sospensione maggiore:

> La vera domanda è...(pausa grande) possiamo fidarci?